# Ping IP Address with VBA code and return results in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have some visual basic code (see below) that tests an IP connection in column B (of an excel spreadsheet) and puts whether or not it is connected or un-reachable in column c, I was just wondering if you could help me I would like it to be green if 'connected', and any other result would be red.

Also, could this script be run automatically on an hourly or daily basis?

Many Thanks,
Andy

```
Function GetPingResult(Host)

   Dim objPing As Object
   Dim objStatus As Object
   Dim strResult As String

   Set objPing = GetObject("winmgmts:{impersonationLevel=impersonate}"). _
       ExecQuery("Select * from Win32_PingStatus Where Address = '" & Host & "'")

   For Each objStatus In objPing
      Select Case objStatus.StatusCode
         Case 0: strResult = "Connected"
         Case 11001: strResult = "Buffer too small"
         Case 11002: strResult = "Destination net unreachable"
         Case 11003: strResult = "Destination host unreachable"
         Case 11004: strResult = "Destination protocol unreachable"
         Case 11005: strResult = "Destination port unreachable"
         Case 11006: strResult = "No resources"
         Case 11007: strResult = "Bad option"
         Case 11008: strResult = "Hardware error"
         Case 11009: strResult = "Packet too big"
         Case 11010: strResult = "Request timed out"
         Case 11011: strResult = "Bad request"
         Case 11012: strResult = "Bad route"
         Case 11013: strResult = "Time-To-Live (TTL) expired transit"
         Case 11014: strResult = "Time-To-Live (TTL) expired reassembly"
         Case 11015: strResult = "Parameter problem"
         Case 11016: strResult = "Source quench"
         Case 11017: strResult = "Option too big"
         Case 11018: strResult = "Bad destination"
         Case 11032: strResult = "Negotiating IPSEC"
         Case 11050: strResult = "General failure"
         Case Else: strResult = "Unknown host"
      End Select
      GetPingResult = strResult
   Next

   Set objPing = Nothing

End Function

Sub GetIPStatus()

  Dim Cell As Range
  Dim ipRng As Range
  Dim Result As String
  Dim Wks As Worksheet


Set Wks = Worksheets("Sheet1")

Set ipRng = Wks.Range("B3")
Set RngEnd = Wks.Cells(Rows.Count, ipRng.Column).End(xlUp)
Set ipRng = IIf(RngEnd.Row < ipRng.Row, ipRng, Wks.Range(ipRng, RngEnd))

  For Each Cell In ipRng
    Result = GetPingResult(Cell)
    Cell.Offset(0, 1) = Result
  Next Cell

End Sub
```

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for posting your Ping code. I found that incredibly useful!

Answer (score 4):

You don't need code for this. Turn all the cells red, then add conditional formatting to make it green when you want.

Home > Conditional Formatting > New Rule > Use a formula...

```
=C2="Connected"
```

and format to green.  If you want to do it in code, you can add some lines in your For Each loop

```
If Result = "Connected" Then
    Cell.Offset(0,1).Font.Color = vbGreen
Else
    Cell.Offset(0,1).Font.Color = vbRed
End If
```

Comment: This is great thanks, is it possible for the cells (coloumb C & F) (i.e connected, request timed out, etc) to be cleared before the ping request starts and could i have the ping request in another columb so for example A B C D E F1 - Router A 192.168.1.1 Connected Computer A 192.168.1.2 Connected 2 - Router B 192.168.1.8 Connected Computer B 192.168.1.9 Request Timed Out Many Thanks, Andy

Comment: That's a different question. You should make a new question.

Answer (score 1):

To have this run automatically at certain intervals, check out [this link.](http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/run-macro-on-time.htm)

Here's the relevant code:

```
Public dTime As Date
Dim lNum As Long

Sub RunOnTime()
    dTime = Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 10) 'Change this to set your interval
    Application.OnTime dTime, "RunOnTime"

    lNum = lNum + 1
    If lNum = 3 Then
        Run "CancelOnTime" 'You could probably omit an end time, but I think the program would eventually crash
    Else
        MsgBox lNum
    End If

End Sub

Sub CancelOnTime()
    Application.OnTime dTime, "RunOnTime", , False
End Sub
```

I would recommend including a `ThisWorkbook.Save` line as I can't speak to how long this will run without crashing, and I would imagine you could see problems if you left it for days at a time.