# Excel VBA - Powershell don't exit | How to hide CMD

Tags: excel, powershell, vba

I have this code that I am running:

```
Public Function checkhost(hostname As String)
    'bla bal...
    strexec = "powershell -WindowStyle Hidden -Command ping " & hostname & " -n 1"
    Set oExec = WshShell.exec(strexec)
    'bla bla...
End Function
```

From my Excel document, the shell does not close - it remains open. The same code does work, if I use it in Powershell.

With cmd it works fine but I want to hide the cmd window.

```
strexec = "%comspec% /C %WINDIR%\system32\ping.exe " & hostname & " -n 1"
Set oExec = WshShell.exec(strexec)
```

AFAIK the only way to hide CMD is to use WshShell.Run but I don't know how to change my existing code. Can anyone suggest a solution?

**Complete code**

```
    Public Function checkhost(hostname As String)

    Dim WshShell As Variant
    Set WshShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")

    Dim ReturnErrorLevel As Variant
    strexec = "powershell -WindowStyle Hidden -Command ping " & hostname & " -n 1"
    Set oExec = WshShell.exec(strexec)



    Do Until oExec.Status = 1
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    Loop

    Result = Split(oExec.StdOut.readAll, vbCrLf, , vbTextCompare)

    For Each Item In Result
        Debug.Print Item
        If InStr(1, Item, "Ping request could not find host", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            checkhoststatus = "0.0.0.0"
            Exit For
        End If

        If InStr(1, Item, "Request timed out.", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            checkhoststatus = "0.0.0.0"
           Exit For
        End If

        If InStr(1, Item, "Reply from ", vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
            checkhoststatus = Mid(Item, 12, InStr(1, Item, ":", vbTextCompare) - 12)
            Exit For
        End If

    Next Item
End Function
```

Comment: this looks a more solid approach http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020077/ping-ip-address-with-vba-code-and-return-results-in-excel

Comment: `;` is a separator for commands in powershell. You can tell PS to exit after your ping command like this: `strexec = "powershell -WindowStyle Hidden -Command ping " & hostname & " -n 1 ;exit"`

Comment: @JamesC. Thanks and nice to know but nothing has changed, the window keeps, don't exit.
The script remains in the loop and wait for closing the shell.

    `Do Until oExec.Status = 1
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    Loop`

Comment: Ah that's a shame, next try is WshShell.Run which you'd use like this: `Set oExec = WshShell.Run strexec,0,True` The `0` hides CMD prompt and `True` makes the script wait for the command to finish before it continuing. (I don't have Excel so can't test this so am putting it as a comment not an answer)

Comment: Since your evaluation of the ping results resolves to a true/false why not use test-connection instead of ping `strexec = "powershell -WindowStyle Hidden -Command test-Connection " & hostname & " -count 1 -quiet"`

Comment: @JamesC.
If I try your last code I get a "runtime error 13 type mismatch", if I change the code to `Set oExec = WshShell.Run(strexec, 0, True)` the error massage is "compile error object required".

@LotPings
Hi, thank you. Also with your code the powershell remains open after the run.

@all
Should I upload the complete document?