# How to add connect timeout for putty sftp command

Tags: excel, sftp, putty, pscp, vba

Currently I am working in Excel vba. I dont know much about it.

I am doing file transfer operation using putty sftp command,
I am using below code for the same.
I have also installed winscp & putty on my pc.

My code is:

```
Dim shell As Object
Dim command As String
Dim errorCode As Integer
Dim waitOnReturn As Boolean: waitOnReturn = True
Dim windowStyle As Integer: windowStyle = 0

Set shell = VBA.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

command = "cmd.exe /c echo y |"C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\pscp.exe" 
           -sftp -P 22 -l Username_Here -pw Password_Here
            SRC_IP_Address_Here:File_Path_Here " " Destination_Path_Here

' error code is 0 if all ok otherwise 1
errorCode = shell.Run(command, windowStyle, waitOnReturn)
```

Above  code works fine if ip address & destination path exists,
but if ip address is not reachable in network excel takes 20-30 seconds for response & errorCode  = 1.

Is it possible to modify above code in such a way that it should give me response only within 10 sec?

How can I set putty sftp connection timeout in above code?

I tried following links but not getting any result:

https://patrickmn.com/aside/how-to-keep-alive-ssh-sessions/

https://www.computerhope.com/unix/sftp.htm

https://library.netapp.com/ecmdocs/ECMP1196993/html/GUID-02FF883B-9913-4137-BC8B-5CB47282B944.html

https://tartarus.org/~simon/putty-snapshots/htmldoc/Chapter5.html

Comment: Before running `pscp` make sure that the remote host is exists.

Comment: @AlexP Can you elaborate how to do this?(do you mean using ping command or something)

Comment: `ping -n 1 -w 100 SRC_IP_HERE && ...`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020077/ping-ip-address-with-vba-code-and-return-results-in-excel

Comment: @AlexP

Thank you so much for your help. 
Can we add connect timeout in above code? I have added it in my code, as shown in below but not working. 

"cmd.exe /c echo y |"C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\pscp.exe" -sftp **-oConnectTimeout = 100** -P 22 -l username_here -pw password_here ip_here:path_here " " Destination_path_here

Comment: I don't know of `-oConnectTimeout` in `pscp`.

Comment: There's no `-oConnectTimeout` in pscp.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Thanks for your help