# Pinging IP addresses in excel using VB

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to make a excel doc where I can see when a device is down however im terrible at VB. I used to use something called Cacti to manage this but it got too complicated to style the boxes and eventually stopped checking pings etc.

I was wondering if anyone could help me start something or already has a template out there I was looking to hopefully get something like this.

[image: Excel Ping]

Comment: Does this provide an answer? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020077/ping-ip-address-with-vba-code-and-return-results-in-excel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ping IP Address with VBA code and return results in Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21020077/ping-ip-address-with-vba-code-and-return-results-in-excel)

Answer (score 0):

have a look at "Network Tools For Excel". It's an Excel add-in with built in ping functionality.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30285037)